# Alternative python snowflake.connector authentication method to avoid snowflake.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 429 Too Many Requests

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, okta-api

I have multiple different python scripts running somewhat parallel (concurrently within milliseconds of each other) where I have to connect to Snowflake and execute queries.

Initially I had my connector like so, using okta url for authentication.

```
def connect_to_snowflake(role='my_role'):
     snwf_user = 'user'
     snwf_pass = 'pass'

     return snowflake.connector.connect(
                     user=snwf_user,
                     password=snwf_pass,
                     account='my-account',
                     authenticator='https://{company}.okta.com',
                     role=role,
                     warehouse='my_warehouse',
                     database='my_db',
                     schema='public')
```

This worked when I had just a couple scripts running concurrently but now it's scaled up and I get the error

```
Error: snowflake.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 250003 (08001): 429 Too Many Requests: post https://company.okta.com/api/v1/authn
```

I looked at other auth methods like potentially caching the connection but nothing seemed to solve my problem. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I also met this issue and if possible, can you try using another username and password? The server generally limits requests by user, not by company.

Comment: Which other username and password would I use though? That's a good point that it may be throttling me since I'm requesting as a user and not a company, but how would I submit the request as an enterprise?

Comment: The HTTP 429 seems to be coming from Okta and not Snowflake. Have you looked at connection caching options like described [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use.html#using-connection-caching-to-minimize-the-number-of-prompts-for-authentication-optional).

Comment: Could you try using RSA certificate based authentication instead? What are the restrictions on your connection environment? Which solutions are possible are going to depend on your environmental / company restrictions.

Failing that, could you combine your scripts to share the single connector between them?

Comment: @Sergiu Yea that is why i'm asking for alternative auth methods as opposed to okta or solutions that bypass the okta error. I have seen that caching document you linked however the docs are not clear to me on what to do. It lists two steps there, 1: run the command to set caching to true...2: pip install "snowflake-connector-python[secure-local-storage]". What next? is there something from that package that I need to incorporate into the connect function?

Comment: @GuyAltman if you're using MFA, you probably also need to enable [MFA Token Caching](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-mfa.html#using-mfa-token-caching-to-minimize-the-number-of-prompts-during-authentication-optional). However, if you are running each script separately, then I suspect caching may not work because the scripts would be caching their own connection parameters? [This](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/349#issuecomment-745521054) shows how connection caching should work within a script, but doesn't suggest it working between scripts.

Comment: @GuyAltman I mean a possible way is to ask the IT department to create multiple service accounts, and use the usernames and passwords of these accounts. It's a dirty way, but there's actually no good solution except reducing the number of requests you make. Servers are not cheap, so they have to limit it. One compromise you can make is you can decrease the concurrency these Python scripts. You have to wait longer, but it reduces the chance of max request error.

Comment: User @JamesGoodhand also suggests good method. If you can make it work, better follow his way.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue was resolved in latest JDBC driver v3.13.27
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/JDBC-Driver-Release-Notes